# How to update g++ compiler on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I tried using [this](https://arvindrao.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/installing-latest-gccg-via-homebrew/) tutorial to download the newest version of g++, and I changed the version number from 4.7 to the newest (which is believe is) 8.1. But I get the following errors

```
Error: No available formula with the name "gcc81"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Does anyone know how to update my g++ version? This is what I get when I try to find out my current version.

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Sorry Im such a noob, I really trying to learn here.

Comment: I don't know much about homebrew, but it seems you don't have any gcc installed. What you get when you run `g++` is actually apple's installed `clang++` compiler. It is a strange thing apple do, to alias `g++`. So you don't need to "upgrade" so much as "install". Anyway, what happens if you try `brew install gcc`, without a version?

Comment: I think you might be going against the grain trying to use gcc on OSX these days - Apple are pushing hard to move people over to clang.  Why do you need it?

Comment: Homebrew gcc 8 is installed by `brew install gcc`. You can `brew search gcc` to find options, and `brew info gcc` to determine what version is offered in the gcc package. To prevent the homebrew installed gcc from conflicting with the mac one, homebrew puts a postfix of `-8` on all the files, so `gcc` is invoked by `gcc-8`, `g++` is invoked by `g++-8`. So if you're using makefiles, you would set the environment variables `CC=gcc-8 CXX=g++-8`, and these should carry into makefile, or configure scripts.

Answer (score 11):

I know this post is a little old but I can shine some light regarding how to accomplish this.

Firstly, to install `gcc`/`g++` using Homebrew, you should use the following command as mentioned in the comments above: `brew install gcc`

After doing this, Homebrew should place the installed binaries/symlinks in the correct folders.

To correctly setup the `gcc`/`g++` command on mac to use the version you just downloaded, I do this by not changing the symlinks `gcc`/`g++` but instead creating aliases for both `gcc` and `g++` within my shell environment.

```
alias gcc='gcc-10'
alias g++='g++-10'
```

`gcc-10` and `g++-10` were downloaded using Homebrew. When doing this, Homebrew places `gcc-10` and `g++-10` in /usr/local/bin (which is on the path) and it allows you to create an alias for the regular `gcc`/`g++` commands which point to the versions installed by Homebrew.

After doing this, running the command `g++ --version` should give you the following:

```
g++-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

You may need to restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` depending on the type of shell you're using.